# how to load data in table view result of search bar swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I want to display the search result of a SearchBar in a tableView and I do not know how.

[image]

when i type a Destination in the TextField, everything is works just fine, but when i type in the SearchBar is not working:

[image]

Here is how to call a func to search in [String]:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {


public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let substring = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    DestinoP.searchDestinos(substring)

    return true

}}
```

here is how to show the result:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let index = indexPath.row as Int

    isSearching = true // this is just for SearchBar
    if isSearching {
        if let str = autoCompleteDestino[index].desDestino {
            cell.textLabel?.text = str
        }
    }

    return cell
}}
```

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if isSearching { // this is just for SearchBar
        return autoCompleteDestino.count
    }

    return autoCompleteDestino.count

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!

    destinoSearch.text = selectedCell.textLabel!.text!
    busquedaDestinosText.text = selectedCell.textLabel!.text!

}}
```

this is how i try to show the result when i type in the SearchBar:

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    let stringOfUser = (busquedaDestinosText.text)

    DestinoP.searchDestinos(stringOfUser!)

    if  destinoSearch.text == "" {
        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
        print(isSearching)
    } else {
        isSearching = true
        print(isSearching)
        print(autoCompleteDestino)
    }

}}
```

Can help me?

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you should have two arrays in your class `original` and `filtered`

```
var originalData: [String]!
var filteredData: [String]!
```

Add a searchController in your class

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

Setup your `searchController` and add the `searchBar` as the `tableView`'s header

```
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

tblView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Implement the `searchBar`'s `delegate` methods

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchController.searchBar.text = ""
    tblView.reloadData()
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text
    filteredData = originalData.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
        let value: NSString = item as NSString
        return (value.range(of: searchString!, options: .caseInsensitive).location != NSNotFound)
    })
    tblView.reloadData()
}
```

Finally, your `tableView`'s `delegate` methods will look something like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchController.isActive == true && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return filteredData.count
    }
    return originalData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if searchController.isActive == true && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        //RETURN CELLS CREATED FROM FILTERED DATA
    }
    //RETURN CELLS CREATED FROM ORIGINAL DATA
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if searchController.isActive == true && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        //HANDLE ROW SELECTION FROM FILTERED DATA
    }
    //HANDLE ROW SELECTION FROM ORIGINAL DATA
}
```

Comment: Hi Malik..thanks! but in this case i add the Search Bar in the storyboard @IBOutlet weak var destinoSearch: UISearchBar! (not  programmatically). And the way to show the "filteredData or autoCompleteDestino in my case"  is this:                                                      if let str = autoCompleteDestino[index].desDestino {
            cell.textLabel?.text = str
        }                                                                                                             How to show the autoCompleteDestino when type in the SearchBar?

Comment: You will still have to hook in the searchBar `delegate` methods. These methods in turn will filter out the data and reload `tableView`

Answer (score 1):

OK...so i solve my problem. @Malik is open my mind! (thanks for that!)
Finally i put the searchBar programmatically by do this:

```
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Buscar Destinos"
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

and show in my TableView:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

I use UISearchBarDelegate :

```
                                                                              `extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    let stringOfUser = (searchController.searchBar.text!)

    DestinoP.searchDestinos(stringOfUser)

}}
```

Show the result in the tableView:

```
 extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let index = indexPath.row as Int

        if let str = autoCompleteDestino[index].desDestino {
            cell.textLabel?.text = str
        }

    return cell
}}
```

And reloadData of tableView:

```
func mostarResultados( ArrayResultados: [Destinos]) {

    autoCompleteDestino = ArrayResultados
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Thanks!